# How do I write output to screen from systemd service during boot?

Tags: shell-script, centos, systemd, systemd-boot

I have a custom systemd service that runs during the first boot.

If the user has no bootsplash I would like to write to the console and give some info on what's going on. Is there a way to do that from my service?

Here's my systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prepare operator after installation
Before=getty@tty1.service getty@tty2.service getty@rrt3.service getty@tty4.service getty@tty5.service getty@tty6.service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
OnFailure=emergency.target
OnFailureJobMode=replace-irreversibly

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/provision-operator

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: selinux-autorelabel.service does this with `StandardInput=tty` [sic], but I don't know how it works if you _do_ have a bootsplash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `man systemd.directives`, you can search for "output" and find that `StandardOutput=` is documented in in `man systemd.exec`.  There you can find options including `journal+console` to send output to the systemd Journal and the system console. You might also try `kmsg+console`. According to the docs `kmsg` "connects standard output with the kernel log buffer which is accessible via dmesg(1),"

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. I don't have a login prompt in tty1. So it does not show MOTD out of the box.

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
After=getty@tty2.service 
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/bin/cat /etc/motd
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty1
```

Where `oneshot` says: exec only once. `Restart=no` requirement of `oneshot`.
Not sure why there are two `ExecStart` and why "-", this was copy and paste. 
I added `After=` / `ExecStartPre=` because the message did not show up, probably screen was cleared by someone else. So it should be after target "login prompt".

Disclaimer: Use this answer as a collection of ideas. I didn't want them to get lost. Do your own research if you have any questions and feel free to contribute your findings.

This was done on Debian stretch w/o X.